# What is the most scalable PHP-based directory structure for a large site?

Tags: php, directory

I am creating a very large PHP MVC-based site that will have a large library of php classes, javascripts, and many css files (not to mention a large amount of files for the MVC).

For the first time ever, I am actually taking the time to plan out a clean and organized directory structure.

What directory structures do you typically use, and which will be easiest to manuever when there are thousands of files?

Comment: This is just a thought. Have you considered using a PHP MVC framework that already exists, such as CakePHP? I understand there may be a learning curve, but it might be worthwhile to consider the benefits of an open source, popular framework. I've built and maintained my own code for years, but found that it is more scalable to use a third party framework, especially for large sites. You may just find that it will save you time in the long run, and you'll have valuable skills for future outsourcing projects.

Comment: i actually have thought of that...and i might acutally use one in the end...but i just have to be able to do it myself before i can move on:) its a neurotic thing ha

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is my setup. It's worked great for me for small - very large projects (including a social network).
These folders would all live within my main application folder:

- config - contains custom PHP config files
- css - contains the project's CSS files
- helpers - contains 'helper' files (each file is a collection of functions)
- images - contains the project's images
- js - contains the project's Javascript files
- lib - contains PHP classes specific to the project
- modules - My MVC framework allows packaging site sections as modules

  - blog - An example module

    - controllers - contains the controllers for the module
    - models - contains the models for the module
    - views - contains the views for the module
- views - contains views that should be globally accessible (page header, footer, etc)

All the directories could obviously contain sub-folders that would further organize your files. For example, the 'css' folder could have sub-folders named 'web' and 'mobile'. The 'images' folder could contain a 'user_uploaded' folder which could then contain`'profile'. And of course you can add folders as you see fit, in one project I have a folder called 'uploaders' which just contains stand-alone upload scripts.

I also use convenience methods which help construct the filenames of what I want to load. For example, my loadView() will look for the view file in the current module directory, or if you pass an optional $module argument, it will look specifically within that module's folder.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This means all php code, configuration, etc will be visible to everyone unless you do some server magic with something like .htaccess

Comment: OIS is correct. In this setup, if someone knew the file name, they could call it from the browser. I posted this answer before switching to Symfony (which hides all background files) and I definitely recommend moving all non-public files outside of public web access.

Comment: `lib - contains PHP classes specific to the project` Do you mean "not specific" here? I would think lib is for things you write that are general and/or for actual existing libraries that you use. Also, I'm curious - what do you think about the `js` and `css` folders as far as modules go? Would you split up the `js` directory into lib & modules in a similar way?

Answer (score 23):

You should have one directory as web root, where only files you want exposed to the whole internet should reside.

```
project/
 web/
  index.php
  css/
  js/
  images/
 config/
 lib/
```

- web/ is the root shown to visitors
- lib/ is here the library folder, and where autoload look for files.

You can add more subfolders to project/ like controller, modules, view, helper, etc. This depends on your framework.

**EDIT:**

If you use composer (which I recommend) and maybe npm with grunt and less your file structure would be the following:

```
project/
    web/
        js/
        css/
        images/
        index.php
    cli/
    config/
        config.php
    node_modules/
    src/
    test/
    vendor/
    composer.json
    composer.lock
    packages.json
```

- web/ has all your public files
- cli/ scripts and programs to be run from command line NOT the web
- config/ has all your config files (in git you ignore config.php and instead have config.dist.php without usernames, passwords, validation codes and table prefixes/suffixes and other "secrets")
- node_modules/ has all your library files from npm (in git I suggest you put this in a submodule)
- src has all your local PHP files in psr4 structure, set up to autoload in composer.json
- test/ has all your unit tests for your src classes, set up in autload-dev in composer.json (remember to use *composer install --no-dev* on live, maybe add *-o* if you don't have too many classes)
- vendor has all your library files from composer and the ONE AND ONLY autoload.php to be included in web/index.php and any cli scripts (in git I suggest you ignore this vendor folder)

Add other folders and files as required for your project.

For deployment use this structure:

```
/sites/project/ (project is your projectname)
    current (alias to current release folder releases/v1.1.0)
    previous (optional alias to previous release folder releases/v1.0.1)
    releases/
        v1.0.0/ (git checkout of tag v1.0.0)
        v1.0.1/ (git checkout of tag v1.0.1)
        v1.1.0/ (git checkout of tag v1.1.0)
    shared/ (has all your shared files and folders to be aliased in all releases - maybe something like GlusterFS)
```

Make a deployment script. Something like this:

First take backup of db or to copy it to a new database, checkout git repo to new folder with release tag, get all git submodules, run composer install --no-dev, setup any aliases for shared folders and files like uploaded images and configuration files, generate js/css with grunt and less or equivalent, point current alias to the new folder with the tag, run update database script, restart nginx/apache/fpm-php services, run tests to check the website is up.

Have a script to go back to previous version (or a guide so you know what to do).

Comment: Clean and simple but lacks two important folders: `project/tests/` and `project/class/` (so that the `lib` folder can be used for third party libraries). May be you people have other suggestions for the thrid parties structure?

Answer (score 5):

For core files which are included:
approot/inc/

For data access functions and classes are in:
approot/dao/

For javascripts:
approot/scripts/

For CSS:
approot/styles/

For images:
approot/img/

For static content (normally for user profile pictures or uploaded images):
approot/static/

For caches:
approot/caches/

For templates or View files:
approot/templates/

All pages file:
approot/

Structure from [Samstyle PHP Framework](http://code.google.com/p/samstyle-php-framework)

---

The answer I posted here was from 2009. Over the years more standards were published, including [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) which covers the topic on folder structure. I also have a new (and I feel that it's better) folder structure with [Packfire Framework](https://github.com/packfire/app-structure).

Comment: @mauris do you still use this structure?

Comment: @Sarah nope No longer. https://github.com/packfire/config or packages in Packfire are created by me and none of them uses this structure anymore.

Comment: @mauris thanks for getting back to me. I struggle a bit in structuring my folders and I was very interested in seeing how professional developers do it. My folders are everywhere and this forces me to do alot of url rewrite rules. I downloaded the folder but understand what to be looking for.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, you can never plan for this. You can try to follow what frameworks do, but I find I never quite fit exactly into their mold.

I recommend to just keep a good rule of thumb for 20 files in a directory maximum. If you find you need more, just create a few sub directories and move common components in there.

Comment: cool idea on learning from frameworks...but what are some good ones, and where do i find their structures? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is mostly a matter of preference, a quick Google search would reveal many different project structures. But it would be really nice if there were an agreed upon standard. I think this [initiative](https://github.com/php-pds/skeleton) by the PHP Package Development Standards is a good candidate.

This is the directory structure they propose:

- **bin/**: command-line executables
- **config/**: configuration files
- **docs/**: documentation files
- **public/**: web server files
- **resources/**: other resource files
- **src/**: PHP source code
- **tests/**: test code

EDIT:

This is also mentioned in the [PHP The Right Way](https://phptherightway.com) under the section Common Directory structure.

Answer (score 2):

I use codeigniter for small and big projects.
It's MVC feature is moderately good.

- codeIgniter\system\application\config : contain all kind of configuration files like DB,Payment gateway, ftp config, routes and ...
- codeIgniter\system\application\models: contain all kinds of database classes, you should create sub folders according to your need, I used customers, mailData, paymentModel, report, web-service and ....
- codeIgniter\system\application\views: contain all kinds of files that will work as output for clients, you should think of reuse these files if possible. Like the models you had to create sub folder like  administration, reports, email, email_template .....
- codeIgniter\system\application\controllers : this is the most important part. This will help to create SEO url, so you should be more careful about sub folders this time. You can create like  administration, products, reports, orders..... and consider a good name for the functions of the controller class.

These were for the PHP/HTML  file.

Now about the other files:

- codeIgniter\images: for the images
- codeIgniter\scripts: for the Java scripts and their framework
- codeIgniter\styles: for the CSS
- codeIgniter\uploads: for the uploaded files, if you don't want to put files in the DB

For the detail see codeIgniter framework in detail.

Here  "codeIgniter\" is the approot

Comment: Can I put index.php in the web root folder and the rest of PHP in the controller?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**This is the structure i'm using currently,**

```
public/           
  assets/         /* js, css, imgs, ... */
  index.php
src/
  config/         /* for config files */
  helpers/        /* for functions */
  libraries/      /* for free classes that are not MVC classes */
  models/         /* for M in MVC */
  views/          /* for V in MVC */                   
  controllers/    /* for C in MVC */
  vendor/         /* for vendors files */
  uploads/        /* for uploaded images, docs, ... */
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [symfony 1.4](http://www.symfony-project.org) or [symfony 2](http://symfony.com)  dir structure. Choose what's most intuitive to you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this depends on how large the project will become. This is what I used mostly:

project/
    index.php
    img/
    css/
    js/
    views/
    functions/

As long as all the project files are organised...

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question is abit old, I still think it is wise to suggest the latest scaleable application structure which I have been working in my SOA based application and working absolutely fine.

```
myApplication/

    app/
        config/ 
        +         this can include custom MVC structure
    cli/ 
    docker/
    lib/        - most commonly reusable components
    logs/
    public/     - should contain all publicly exposable web contains
    sql/        - db migration stuffs
    tests/      - compulsory test
    tools/      - application addon tools like any kinds of rulset etc
    vendor/
```