# What is the best way to organize files and folders in an object oriented PHP project?

Tags: php, oop, security

What is the best directory structures of an object oriented PHP project? taking security into consideration among the other factors. I usually use these technologies to build websites: OOP PHP/MySql, html, css, javascript/jQuery, ajax and smarty. And I don't want to use a framework right now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387547/what-is-the-most-scalable-php-based-directory-structure-for-a-large-site

Answer (score 3):

Just use [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) with an [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

This way you can organize your folders this way:

```
/
  src
    Model
      User.php
    View
      index.php
    Controller
     HomeController.php
  assets
    img
    js
    css
```

Your `User` class will be like:

```
namespace Model;

class User{ ... }
```

and you can refer to it this way:

```
$user = new \Model\User;
```

or:

```
<?php

use \Model\User;

...
// later in your code
$user = new User;
```

Where's the magic? When you ask for a class, the **autoloader** requires it [and throws an exception if anything goes wrong].

A basic autoloader will look like:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include 'src' . str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class) . '.php';
});
```

It will search classes from `src` folder based on class name, in this case `Model\User`.

---

These are the basics, it's up to you to tweak it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is that the directory structure and file-organizing reflects the application so that it is accessible for development and operation.