# Is there Any CONS of making a big common function file in php / or other languages

Tags: javascript, php, web

I just wanted to ask is there any problem or cons if I keep adding new functions to a single file and if I import this function file everwhere. Currently, I am having 280 Functions in functions.php and 5335 Line of codes in functions.php

I am expecting to add more around 500+ functions in the future. Is there any cons in terms of Best practices / Optimization?

My main focus is on optimization.

Comment: Splitting functions into logical groups helps to find the relevant code.  It's not about performance or loading, it should be about how easy is it to maintain.  One thing to consider is that if you ever have more than 1 person maintaining a project, how can they work on the same code if it's all in 1 file? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648760/project-structure-for-php has some ideas of certain types of project layout.

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61287417/11743318 on how you can use `spl_autoload_register()` to organise your code in a logical way, and only ever load it when it's actually used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with what Nigel Ren already commented above, as much as possible, we want our code to be re-usable. If someone is going to use your code, or if you're going back to your code after weeks of not touching it, having a logical file structure where each file clearly communicates its purpose helps a lot. Look at external libraries for example, if they put functions that aren't related in any way into one file, it would be much harder for us developers to use them. Therefore, having a logical structure helps when you're using someone else's code.