# folder structure in php project

Tags: php, html, directory-structure

I am trying to restructure my project, because all my files are laying around. But is the folder structure looking okay, or is there something I am doing wrong?

public_html is the public site, where a user is not logged in
user_html us the private site, where a user is logged in

I hope I dont put this in the wrong category. In case my apologies, and let me know.

**Folder Structure:**
 [image: Folder Structure]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most scalable PHP-based directory structure for a large site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387547/what-is-the-most-scalable-php-based-directory-structure-for-a-large-site)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387547/what-is-the-most-scalable-php-based-directory-structure-for-a-large-site might help u? This is also opinion based. Just make sure your includes and behind the "front-end" code is in their own directories and not in the root.

Comment: Thank you for that. I will try to look at it.

Comment: Would you recommend to seperate web documents, so there is a folder for php files where a user is not logged in, and a folder for php files after a user is logged in?

Comment: You can seperate the logged in/not-logged in files thats good, but don't make it to complicated. maybe a map Login and put associations with login. But again this is my opinion, I can't give a this is the right way to go answer.

Comment: Thank you a lot everybody. I took a lot of inspiration and made it my own now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you are not using Composer for auto-loading the PSR-4 directory structure is very good and if you use it and want to add in auto-loading later you can so woot. I would imagine most frameworks use this.

The general layout I use is:

```
app_name -> general dir
|  
|____App -> where your app goes
|    |___app_name -> name of application
|    |  |___ models -> these can be whatever you want
|    |  |___controllers
|    |
|    |____templates -> where I put my php/html/twig
|    |
|    |____css -> application specific
|    |    |
|    |    |____app.css
|    |
|    |____js -> application specific
|         | 
|         |____app.js
|
|____Vendor
|    |____php -> php libs
|    |____js  -> frontend css js libs
|
|____Tests
|    |____modelTest
|
|____.git
|____composer.json 
|____bower.json
|____index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at codeigniter dir structure.

better way is to go with php mvc frameworks.